# dynamically show the textbox on selecting the radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have this view

```
@if (@Model.QuestionType == 2)
{
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRadio", "GetQuestion", Model))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label id="l2" for="select-choice-1" class="select">@Model.QuestionText
            </label>
            <br />
            @foreach (var item in Model.Options)
            {

                if (@item.OptionText == "Other")
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="selectedObjects" id="@item.OptionText" value="@item.OptionNumber" onclick="selectRadio(@Model.QuestionNo);" />
                    <input type="text" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_rtxt" style="visibility:hidden;" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="selectedObjects" id="@item.OptionText" value="@item.OptionNumber" />
                }

                <label for="@item.OptionText">
                    @item.OptionText</label> 
            }
            <br />
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="radio_textsubmit" value="Next" />
        </p>
    }
</div>
}
```

when i select a radio button that contains the ***Other*** the textbox should be shown.
By default its hidden.

i written in JS as

```
     function selectRadio(radio) {
        alert(radio);
    }
```

its not firing the selectRadio event at all. do i need to enclose it in form ?

I am doing it in MVC3. what is the solution for it.

any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by contains the 'other'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fire a jquery event on mouse click event of the radiobutton.
here is the jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#radioButtonID").click(function (e) {
            var radioButtonID = $("#radioButtonID").val();

            if (radioButtonID == 1) {
                $("#TextBoxId").css("visibility","visible");
            }
            else{
                $("#TextBoxId").css("visibility","hidden");
            }
```

This will help you

Comment: change the jquery code acc to your requirement .reply me if you need any help.